# Почему перемножаются аннотации в Django?

Tags: python, django, аннотации, queryset, агрегация

Пытаюсь сделать две аннотации для объектов модели Articles: количество просмотров (модель Views) и рейтинг (модель Rating)

Articles:

```py
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    create_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    pub_datetime = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    lasted_datetime = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Автор'
    )
    tags = models.TextField(blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Статья'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Статьи'

        permissions = (
            ("restore_articles", "Can restore Articles"),
            ("publish_articles", "Can publish drafts of Articles"),
            ("view_published", "Can view published Articles"),
            ("view_draft", "Can view drafts of Articles"),
            ("view_deleted", "Can view deleted Articles"),
        )
```

Views:

```py
class Views(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Articles,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Статья',
        related_name='Views'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Пользователь'
    )
    user_ip = models.CharField(
        max_length=16,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    view_datetime = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    view_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=24,
        default='Default'
    )
    view_weight = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.view_datetime

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Просмотры'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Просмотры'
```

Rating:

```py
class Rating(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Articles,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name='Статья',
        related_name='Rating'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Пользователь',
        related_name='Given_rating'
    )
    rating_datetime = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    rating_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=24,
        default='Default'
    )
    rating_weight = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=24,
        default='Active'
    )
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.article) + ": " + "{:+}".format(self.rating_weight)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Рейтинг'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Рейтинг'

        permissions = (
            ("give_rating", "Can give rating to articles"),
            ("manage_rating", "Can manage rating of articles")
        )
        unique_together = ('article', 'user')
```

Сама агрегация происходит здесь:

```py
def stdict(request):
    article_rating = Coalesce(Sum('Rating__rating_weight'), 0)
    poparts = Articles.objects.annotate(
        article_rating=article_rating
    ).annotate(
        views_num=Coalesce(
            Sum(
                'Views__view_weight',
                filter=Q(Views__view_datetime__gte=(
                        datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=-7)
                ).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
            ),
            0
        )
    ).order_by('-views_num')[:3]

    toparts = Articles.objects.annotate(
        article_rating=article_rating
    ).annotate(
        views_num=Coalesce(
            Sum('Views__view_weight'),
            0
        )
    ).order_by('-article_rating')[:3]

    return {
        'user_data': request.user,
        'sidebar_data': {
            'pop_arts': poparts,
            'top_arts': toparts
        }
    }
```

Выводится всё в итоге так:

```html
    <div class="side_articles">
        <h6>Статьи, популярные на этой неделе:</h6>
        {% for post in sidebar_data.pop_arts %}
        <div id="pop-article{{post.id}}">
            <b class="article_title"><a href="/news/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a></b>
            <h6 class="article_views">Просмотров: {{post.views_num}}</h6><br>
            <h6 class="article_datetime">{{post.pub_datetime|date:"d.m.Y H:i"}}</h6>{% if post.lasted_datetime != NULL %} <span class="btn-link article_lasted_datetime" title="{{post.lasted_datetime|date:'d.m.Y H:i'}}">(ред.)</span> {% endif %}
            <h6 class="article_rating">Рейтинг: {{post.article_rating}}</h6><br>
            <h6 class="article_author"><a href="/users/{{post.author}}"><u>{{post.author}}</u></a></h6>
            <p class="article_tags">{{post.tags}}</p>
            <hr>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="side_articles">
        <h6>Статьи с наибольшим рейтингом:</h6>
        {% for post in sidebar_data.top_arts %}
        <div id="top-article{{post.id}}">
            <b class="article_title"><a href="/news/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a></b>
            <h6 class="article_views">Просмотров: {{post.views_num}}</h6><br>
            <h6 class="article_datetime">{{post.pub_datetime|date:"d.m.Y H:i"}}</h6>{% if post.lasted_datetime != NULL %} <span class="btn-link article_lasted_datetime" title="{{post.lasted_datetime|date:'d.m.Y H:i'}}">(ред.)</span> {% endif %}
            <h6 class="article_rating">Рейтинг: {{post.article_rating}}</h6><br>
            <h6 class="article_author"><a href="/users/{{post.author}}"><u>{{post.author}}</u></a></h6>
            <p class="article_tags">{{post.tags}}</p>
            <hr>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Итого: в рейтинге получается перемноженное количество просмотров (за всё время) и рейтинга, в просмотрах так и не понял, по какому принципу получается число. В верхнем блоке количество просмотров отображается за последнюю неделю, в нижнем - за всё время (это так и должно быть), рейтинг и там и там - за всё время.

Результат: (красным - то, что должно быть)
[image: Результат]

P.S. Если убрать аннотацию views_num, то рейтинг начинает отображаться верно. Проблема именно в использовании двух аннотаций. Если прописывать их не последовательно, а внутри одной аннотации через запятую, ничего не меняется - всё так же перемножаются.

P.P.S. Попробовал в промежутке между добалвением первой и второй аннотации вывести результат, и он оказался верным. А вот уже после добавления второй - ломаются оба...

```py
toparts = Articles.objects.annotate(
        article_rating=article_rating
    ).order_by('-article_rating')[:3]  # ).annotate(
    #     views_num=Coalesce(
    #         Sum('Views__view_weight'),
    #         0
    #     )
    # ).order_by('-article_rating')[:3]
    print(
        # toparts[0].views_num,
        toparts[0].article_rating  #Работает
    )
    toparts = toparts.annotate(
        views_num=Sum('Views__view_weight')
    )
    print(
        toparts[0].views_num,      #Сломано
        toparts[0].article_rating  #Сломано
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема описана в [тикете](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060) на офф. сайте Django. Если кратко, то суть в том, что при множественных аннотациях происходит, соответственно, множественное добавление строк из БД, так что поулчается т.н. декартово произведение. Из-за этого и ломается подсчёт. В комментариях есть способ решения через библиотеку [django-sql-utils](https://github.com/martsberger/django-sql-utils) при помощи подзапросов. Есть и другие способы, встроенные в Django, но этот - наиболее удобный, так как всё, что требуется - прописать `Subquery` перед `Sum`. В итоге код получился таким:

```py
def stdict(request):
    article_rating = Coalesce(SubquerySum('Rating__rating_weight'), 0)
    poparts = Articles.objects.annotate(
        article_rating=article_rating
    ).annotate(
        views_num=Coalesce(
            Sum(
                'Views__view_weight',
                filter=Q(Views__view_datetime__gte=(
                        datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=-7)
                ).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
            ),
            0
        )
    ).order_by('-views_num')[:3]

    toparts = Articles.objects.annotate(
        article_rating=article_rating
    ).annotate(
        views_num=Coalesce(
            Sum('Views__view_weight'),
            0
        )
    ).order_by('-article_rating')[:3]
    
    return {
        'user_data': request.user,
        'sidebar_data': {
            'pop_arts': poparts,
            'top_arts': toparts
        }
    }
```